# Dispatching an action in redux toolkit too slow

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, redux, redux-toolkit, dispatch

I am creating a checklist which can have nested items too (same as in trello). After creating a checklist and adding items, though it works fine, but when i try to toggle any item (i can mark it as completed or not completed), I am dispatching an action at that time to update the global state, but it is too slow. It freezes the whole UI.

Here is the relevant code;

```
 dispatch(
        updatecarditem({
          checklistId,
          itemId: index,
          itemStatus: checked,
        }),
      );

 updatecarditem: (state: any, {payload}) => {
      const checklistId = payload.checklistId;
      const itemId = payload.itemId;

      let item =
        state.entities[0]?.checklist?.[checklistId]?.checklistItem?.[itemId];
      if (payload.itemTitle != undefined) item.itemTitle = payload.itemTitle;
      if (payload.itemStatus != undefined) item.itemStatus = payload.itemStatus;
    },
```

So here, i am simply accessing the nested item and updating the itemTitle or status accordingly. When changing the itemStatus (toggling the checkbox), it freezes the whole UI and is too slow to update, though it works but is too slow.

One thing which i can think can solve the problem is if we have async actions. So is there any way to dispatch actions asyncronously (this is a secondary question).

**EDIT**:

This is a rough structure of the components;

My main checklist;

```
export const CheckListItem: FC<CheckListItemProps> = ({item, index}) => {
  const card = useSelector<any, any>(cardDetails);

  const [value, setValue] = useState(item?.checklistTitle);
  const [newItem, setNewItem] = useState('');

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(item?.checklistTitle);
  }, [item?.checklistTitle]);

  const toggleVisible = () => {
    setVisible((prev) => !prev);
  };

  const addCheckistItem = useCallback(() => {
    if (!newItem.length) {
      return;
    }
    const newCItem = {itemTitle: newItem, itemStatus: false};

    updateChecklist([...item?.checklistItem, newCItem]);
    setNewItem('');
  }, [newItem, item?.checklistItem]);

  const updateChecklist = useCallback(
    (clitem = item?.checklistItem) => {
      if (value.length < 3) {
        showToast(
          'error',
          'Checklist name should contain atleast 3 characters',
        );
        return;
      }
      let newls = [...card?.checklist];
      newls[index].checklistTitle = value;
      newls[index].checklistItem = clitem;

      dispatch(
        updatecard({
          checklist: newls,
        }),
      );
    },
    [value, card?.checklist],
  );

  return (
      <VStack style={styles.cardinfoviews}>
       
          <CustomInput
            onSubmit={updateChecklist}
            value={value}
            setValue={setValue}
          />
     
          <VStack style={styles.cardinfoviews}>
            {item?.checklistItem?.map((citem: any, itemindex: number) => (
              <CheckItem // THIS IS THE NESTED COMPONENT
                key={itemindex}
                citem={citem}
                index={itemindex}
                checklistId={index}
              />
            ))}

            <Input
              onSubmitEditing={addCheckistItem}
              value={newItem}
              onChangeText={setNewItem}
              maxLength={40}
              variant="underlined"
              placeholder="Add item..."
            />
          </VStack>
        )
      </VStack>
  );
};
```

Then the nested component;

```
const CheckItem: FC<CheckItemProps> = ({citem, index, checklistId}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(citem?.itemTitle);
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(citem?.itemStatus);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(citem?.itemTitle);
  }, [citem?.itemTitle]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setChecked(citem?.itemStatus);
  }, [citem?.itemStatus]);

  const updatecheckItem = useCallback(
    (checked = citem?.itemStatus) => {
      setChecked(checked);
      dispatch(
        updatecarditem({
          checklistId,
          itemId: index,
          itemStatus: checked,
        }),
      );
    },
    [checklistId, index],
  );

  const updateItemName = useCallback(() => {
    if (value.length < 3) {
      showToast('error', 'Item name should contain atleast 3 characters');
      return;
    }

    dispatch(
      updatecarditem({
        checklistId,
        itemId: index,
        itemTitle: value,
      }),
    );
  }, [value, index, checklistId]);


  return (
      <Checkbox
        value={citem?.itemTitle}
        isChecked={checked}
        onChange={updatecheckItem}>
          <Input
            w="85%"
            onSubmitEditing={updateItemName}
            variant="unstyled"
            value={value}
            onChangeText={setValue}
            multiline
            numberOfLines={1}
            blurOnSubmit
          />
      </Checkbox>
  );
};
```

**EDIT** Found that, it is bacause of too many re-renders. Fixing that now. If anyone can see the issues in the above code which can be causing too many re-renders, please comment down.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a whole lot going on here in the reducer. Redux state updates are generally pretty quick. What else is the app doing when you toggle a checkbox? Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] so it is easier for readers here to see what all the code is doing?

Comment: I am calling an api inside the useEffect after the changes occur in the redux store but i commented that and it is still pretty slow, I think an important thing to mention would be, the component is nested inside another component and the new value is passed as a prop and updated in the local state using useEffect. will update the question accordingly.

Comment: Very likely this is caused by too much of your app rerendering because you have `useSelector` calls that select too much of your state.
(Edit: or that weird useState/useEffect stuff you just wrote about - that adds another render on top. Why do you do that?)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "too much of your state", i mean, i am selecting the portion which i need in a screen, then some of that data is passed as props to the nested components. Is there any better flow, like directly accessing the state in the child component (but i think that will be selecting too much of the state and just repeating the code)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "the component is nested inside another component"? Is a component being declared inside another component? Either way, I think we need to see a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] now to really see what is going on. Just FYI, "passed as a prop and updated in the local state using useEffect" is a common React anti-pattern. We don't generally duplicate state.

Comment: @DrewReese updated my question. Please check that.

Comment: @phry that usestate/useeffect is used because I provide an option to update the values too (same as in trello, where a user can click the card name etc and can edit it there).

Comment: It is clear now that redux is not slow here, my components are as there are a number of re-renders in the main component (where the above mentioned components are used). I cannot share the whole code here (sorry for that), but can you please check the above two components too and mention the possible reasons for too much re-rendering @DrewReese

Comment: We don't need to see any private company code (*if that's the concern*), just enough of a code example that is reproducible. If possible, could you try also creating a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live? The goal is for us to identify the issue and propose a solution that you can (*hopefully*) take and apply against your actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was not related to actions being dispatched but the way i was accessing the data from store (thanks to @phry), I was selecting too much of the state which caused unnecessary re-renders as the data was being changed from multiple child components. Fixed the re-rendering but still some optimisation needed in the child components.